# How to show Quote Tweets only through Advanced Search

Tags: twitter, twitter-api, twitter-search

I'd like to be able to see only quote tweets quoting my Tweets.
This is missing from the "Mentions Only" notification filter.

Seeing all notifications includes a lot of noise, like Retweets and Likes.

I'd like to see comments and quote tweets only.

Haven't figured out a way how to do get Quote Tweets only.

If I need a Twitter client or go through API that'd be ok, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better solution, you can just do it through an ordinary Twitter search as follows:

```
"twitter.com/CorneliusRoemer/status" -from:@CorneliusRoemer
```

Of course, replace `CorneliusRoemer` with the account whose quote tweets you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out at least for v2 of the Twitter API.

The following query works with Twurl, and should also work generally:

```
twurl /2/tweets/search/recent\?query\="twitter.com/CorneliusRoemer"\ -is:retweet
```

So the query needs to contain the `twitter.com/USERNAME` and the qualifier `-is:retweet` which suppresses pure retweets, causing only quote tweets of user `USERNAME` to be shown.